# Gradient Descent algorithm not converging in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, machine-learning, functional-programming, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the gradient descent algorithm in Andrew Ng's ML course. After reading in the data, I try to implement the following, updating my list of theta values 1000 times, with the expectation of some convergence.[image]

The algorithm in question is `gradientDescent`. I know that typically a cause of this problem is that alpha can be too large, but when I change alpha by a factor of `n` for example, my results change by a factor of `n`. The same happens when I change `iterations` by a factor of `n`. I want to say this could be to do with haskell's laziness, but I'm completely unsure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
module LR1V where

import qualified Data.Matrix as M
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
import qualified Data.Vector as V

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- getContents
    let lns = lines contents :: [String]
        entries = map (splitOn ",") lns :: [[String]]
        mbPoints = mapM readPoints entries :: Maybe [[Double]]
    case mbPoints of 
        Just points -> runData points
        _           -> putStrLn "Error: it is possible the file is incorrectly formatted"

readPoints :: [String] -> Maybe [Double]
readPoints dat@(x:y:_) = return $ map read dat
readPoints _ = Nothing

runData :: [[Double]] -> IO ()
runData pts = do
    let (mxs,ys) = runPoints pts
        c = M.ncols mxs
        m = M.nrows mxs
        thetas = M.zero 1 (M.ncols mxs)
        alpha = 0.01
        iterations = 1000
        results = gradientDescent mxs ys thetas alpha m c iterations
    print results

runPoints :: [[Double]] -> (M.Matrix Double, [Double])
runPoints pts = (xs, ys) where
    xs = M.fromLists $ addX0 $ map init pts
    ys = map last pts

-- X0 will always be 1
addX0 :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]]
addX0 = map (1.0 :)

-- theta is 1xn and x is nx1, where n is the amount of features
-- so it is safe to assume a scalar results from the multiplication
hypothesis :: M.Matrix Double -> M.Matrix Double -> Double
hypothesis thetas x = 
    M.getElem 1 1 (M.multStd thetas x)

gradientDescent :: M.Matrix Double
                   -> [Double] 
                   -> M.Matrix Double
                   -> Double 
                   -> Int 
                   -> Int 
                   -> Int
                   -> [Double]
gradientDescent mxs ys thetas alpha m n it = 
    let x i = M.colVector $ M.getRow i mxs
        y i = ys !! (i-1)
        h i = hypothesis thetas (x i)
        thL = zip [1..] $ M.toList thetas :: [(Int, Double)]
        z i j = ((h i) - (y i))*(M.getElem i j $ mxs)
        sumSquares j = sum [z i j | i <- [1..m]]
        thetaJ t j = t - ((alpha * (1/ (fromIntegral m))) * (sumSquares j))
        result = map snd $ foldl (\ts _ -> [(j,thetaJ t j) | (j,t) <- ts]) thL [1..it] in
    result
```

and the data...

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
7.4764,4.3483
8.5781,12
6.4862,6.5987
5.0546,3.8166
5.7107,3.2522
14.164,15.505
5.734,3.1551
8.4084,7.2258
5.6407,0.71618
5.3794,3.5129
6.3654,5.3048
5.1301,0.56077
6.4296,3.6518
7.0708,5.3893
6.1891,3.1386
20.27,21.767
5.4901,4.263
6.3261,5.1875
5.5649,3.0825
18.945,22.638
12.828,13.501
10.957,7.0467
13.176,14.692
22.203,24.147
5.2524,-1.22
6.5894,5.9966
9.2482,12.134
5.8918,1.8495
8.2111,6.5426
7.9334,4.5623
8.0959,4.1164
5.6063,3.3928
12.836,10.117
6.3534,5.4974
5.4069,0.55657
6.8825,3.9115
11.708,5.3854
5.7737,2.4406
7.8247,6.7318
7.0931,1.0463
5.0702,5.1337
5.8014,1.844
11.7,8.0043
5.5416,1.0179
7.5402,6.7504
5.3077,1.8396
7.4239,4.2885
7.6031,4.9981
6.3328,1.4233
6.3589,-1.4211
6.2742,2.4756
5.6397,4.6042
9.3102,3.9624
9.4536,5.4141
8.8254,5.1694
5.1793,-0.74279
21.279,17.929
14.908,12.054
18.959,17.054
7.2182,4.8852
8.2951,5.7442
10.236,7.7754
5.4994,1.0173
20.341,20.992
10.136,6.6799
7.3345,4.0259
6.0062,1.2784
7.2259,3.3411
5.0269,-2.6807
6.5479,0.29678
7.5386,3.8845
5.0365,5.7014
10.274,6.7526
5.1077,2.0576
5.7292,0.47953
5.1884,0.20421
6.3557,0.67861
9.7687,7.5435
6.5159,5.3436
8.5172,4.2415
9.1802,6.7981
6.002,0.92695
5.5204,0.152
5.0594,2.8214
5.7077,1.8451
7.6366,4.2959
5.8707,7.2029
5.3054,1.9869
8.2934,0.14454
13.394,9.0551
5.4369,0.61705
```

When `alpha` is `0.01`, my thetas evaluate to `[58.39135051546406,653.2884974555699]`. When `alpha` is `0.001` my values become `[5.839135051546473,65.32884974555617]`. When `iterations` is changed to 10,000 my values return to what they were before.

Comment: How about trying a simpler example dataset?

Comment: I'll give it a shot with a set with a clear linear fit @leftaroundabout

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with each run of updating theta values, the approximation function `h(x)` was using the initial `theta` vector each time, rather than the updated vector. Now, I get an alright approximation of my theta values. However, increasing the number of iterations by a large factor changes my results in an odd way.

Comment: You sound edit your question to indicate exactly what you changed and how, and explain what is odd about the current behavior.